# How do I lock my MacBook?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, macbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a keystroke that can lock the Mac OS X screensaver?](https://superuser.com/questions/11561/is-there-a-keystroke-that-can-lock-the-mac-os-x-screensaver)

Is there no feature to lock the current logged in user like in Windows or can I only log off or switch off?

Comment: This is similar to  [Is there a keystroke that can lock the Mac OS X screensaver?](http://superuser.com/questions/11561/is-there-a-keystroke-that-can-lock-the-mac-os-x-screensaver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the settings for keychain access there is an option to show the keychain access icon on the menu bar.

This gives you a two-click method to lock the screen.

Comment: In the preferences for Keychain Access set the Show in Status bar to TRUE and then from the status bar you can log the screen

Comment: I use this daily.

Answer (score 5):

In System Preferences, under Security, check the box that says "Require password to wake this computer from sleep or screen saver", and check the "Disable automatic login" box.  This will require your password once the screen saver becomes active, or if the box falls to sleep.

You can also set up Exposé with a hot-corner for turning on the screen saver.  System Preferences => Exposé & Spaces => Exposé (tab-like-thing), and then choose which screen corner to put it in.

Comment: that's what I do :)

Answer (score 0):

I just started using Shift-Ctrl-Eject in combination with "require password to wake this computer from sleep or screen saver". Shift-Ctrl-Eject immediately turns off the screen and external monitors.

Answer (score 0):

In the user menu (upper right, showing current user's name), select "Show Login Window".

Answer (score 0):

Twocanoes software has a piece of software that does this called "salute".  The developer is great and I've been using this for years.  So set your preferences to lock the screen when screensaver is activated (System Preferences > Security), hit "ctrl+cmd+delete" and then "enter".

http://www.twocanoes.com/salute/