# Can a Macbook lock the screen without closing the cover?

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a keystroke that can lock the Mac OS X screensaver?](https://superuser.com/questions/11561/is-there-a-keystroke-that-can-lock-the-mac-os-x-screensaver)

or using some complicated steps?  maybe just 1 keystroke?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open up `Keychain Access` from your Applications/Utilities folder, in preferences you can enable "Show Status in Menu Bar" to add a menu bar item to lock your screen quite easily.

Also I fond out that you can press `Ctrl+Shift+⏏` (eject) to put the screen to sleep (and locked)