# Keyboard shortcut for locking screen

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a keystroke that can lock the Mac OS X screensaver?](https://superuser.com/questions/11561/is-there-a-keystroke-that-can-lock-the-mac-os-x-screensaver)

Is there a keyboard shortcut for locking my screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a keystroke that can lock the Mac OS X screensaver?](http://superuser.com/questions/11561/is-there-a-keystroke-that-can-lock-the-mac-os-x-screensaver) (and its many duplicates that are listed in the "Linked" section in that question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another way that does not require additional software: Go to System Preferences - Security - Require password immediately after sleep or screen saver begins.

You can then use ctrl-shift-eject to sleep your monitor, and a password will be required to bring it back.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-Eject on my Macbook Pro

Comment: Nice! Though in general I wouldn't recommend duplicating answers: what about posting this at [Is there a keystroke that can lock the Mac OS X screensaver?](http://superuser.com/questions/11561/is-there-a-keystroke-that-can-lock-the-mac-os-x-screensaver) too? There is [some answer](http://superuser.com/questions/11561/is-there-a-keystroke-that-can-lock-the-mac-os-x-screensaver/11589#11589) there that mentions the keystroke, but that is missing the actual locking. (I *could* edit your answer into that one, but well...)

Comment: Can anyone try this on a machine without an optical disc drive (hence: on a new machine that has Eject replaced with the power button)?

Answer (score 1):

Try Macloc, and then assign it a keyboard shortcut

[About MacLoc](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/networking_security/macloc.html)
This simple application activates the Fast User Switching feature built-in to Mac OS X. After clicking on MacLoc, it will appear that you’ve logged out, however upon entering your username and password, all open documents and applications will be right where you left them. MacLoc is the perfect solution when you need to step out of the room for a moment.

Comment: Nice. I wonder if this also uses the same screen that Fast User Switching uses (which then actually *does* reveal that one is actually logged in)? (To assign a keyboard shortcut to the built-in Fast User Switching also see the duplicate questions.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide on how to do it: [How to lock your Mac with a keyboard shortcut.](http://www.switchingtomac.com/tutorials/how-to-lock-your-mac-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/)

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Windows XP, press the [Windows logo key + L](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294317) to lock your computer.

Comment: It's tagged with "osx", I don't think he's using Windows XP.

Comment: Ye gods. My bad; I *so* didn't even notice. I need to go to bed.

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but: each post does have a "delete" link...!